# Passing range of number like 0 -100 in an example section of cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, karate, gherkin

I am trying to pass the range of number in index from 0 - 100 or if I have n number then 0 to n. how do I do that ? Could you please help me with the sample code in cucumber / karate ?

```
Examples:
  | index | number | em_number |
  | 0     | 1      |   10          |
  | 1     | 1      |   10          |
  | 2     | 1      |   10          |
  | 3     | 1      |   10          |
  | 4     | 1      |   10          |
```

Comment: Welcome, please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: hi I have tried using javascript, but I didn't succeed in that. I am a beginner and appreciate if you could help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to spend some time on fundamentals before trying to over-complicate your tests.

That said, karate has a built-in function. Try this:

```
* def nums = karate.range(5, 9)
* match nums == [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And then please read the docs on JSON transforms: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms